# How do I show www. and https:// in Chrome 79?

Tags: google-chrome, https, www

I just updated Chrome to version 79, and I noticed that prefixes like `https://` and `www.` have disappeared again. Before, I fixed this by setting the `omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme-and-subdomains` flag in `chrome://flags` to Disabled. However, that flag isn't there anymore, and I don't see what it was replaced with. What's the new way to fix this?

Update: I tried setting `temporary-unexpire-flags-m76` to Enabled. While this brought back the above flag, it no longer works. As soon as I set it and relaunch, it gets set right back to Default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These instructions are from https://jdtechservices.net/tools/.

The first method, which I prefer, is to add a parameter to your Chrome shortcut inside the target field:

```
--disable-features=OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlScheme,OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlTrivialSubdomains
```

If you are using Windows it will look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlScheme,OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlTrivialSubdomains
```

like this

[image: Capture.png]

The second method is to install an extension, but this will consume some memory:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/suspicious-site-reporter/jknemblkbdhdcpllfgbfekkdciegfboi

Comment: `http://` still not shown... any idea how to show it?

Comment: @dentarg Not a direct answer, but [UnGoogled Chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) will (potentially) show e.g. `http`. You can get up-to-date unofficial builds [here](https://chromium.woolyss.com/).

Comment: Downside to installing Google's Suspicious Site Reporter extension is that it gives Google permission to read the browsing history. - [Ghacks](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/12/13/google-removes-options-to-always-show-www-in-the-chrome-browsers-address-bar/)

Comment: @dentarg make sure to paste it into the target field https://i.postimg.cc/63tC0vnm/Capture.png

Comment: @theggputest55 I'm on macOS. I start Chrome like this `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app --args --disable-features=OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlScheme,OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlTrivialSubdomains` (example with Canary, but I do the same with regular Chrome)

Comment: @dentarg Yes according to this
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018494/how-to-add-launch-parameter-to-google-chrome-on-mac
 you are on the right path

Comment: This does NOT WORK: I used this from a terminal: `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-features=OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlScheme,OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlTrivialSubdomains`

Answer (score 4):

Found an alternate solution on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/e9wxfd/chrome_79_how_to_restore_httphttpswww_using_your/) Reddit discussion

1. Create a new folder and name it **`Restore URL`**.
2. Paste the following into a text editor and save as **`manifest.json`** in the new folder.

`{ "name": "Restore URL", "version": "1.0", "description": "Restores http and www in the omnibox", "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAowA8wOUQ8ShyITJ15B9rcJrnoolyo+OLj07g8QWBlEBikgszYwlbc88OIRL+dJOASok3yG6RQ60fvIjBrtNEk1yQZJfNwF/CN0jFrkE3HN3xVMoX0XIQPB93kDZARcfR5nwU3RUgwwWGTqt69KSSU8QzRRQJSEgM8GENa3OBhw1UBn/I/RbhaFcTykJSomo9j55goJwNzUhXTJk458DQ5diY+gWMadDXlDBa8cciCVlaGOjBV5ezmxnD6p1GXhrvyEKZP8IlreDJC2Nw9hxrT3GIo1FzbmeDPANKJ9pkY1H3LOVsGJDtytBpD/FRErlvfkJVqp3N5ifF2EQ8lOAHrQIDAQAB", "manifest_version": 2 }`

3. Go to **`chrome://extensions/`** and enable developer mode.
4. Click "Load Unpacked" and select the folder with your **`manifest.json`** file.

This installs an *unpacked* extension (not from Chrome Store) that fakes it's ID to look like Google's [**Suspicious Site Reporter**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/suspicious-site-reporter/jknemblkbdhdcpllfgbfekkdciegfboi) without the bloat or privacy issues included within the original.

You should now have http, https and www restored until Chrome removes this workaround.

**Note**: This will remove Google's official "Suspicious Site Reporter" if already installed. You wouldn't need this solution if the official extension was installed anyway.. unless you *want* to replace it!

**Incognito**:
If you want to enable it in incognito, click on the extension icon [R] > Manage extensions > enable the option "Allow in incognito”.

**To always run Chrome/Chromium** with this unpacked extension:

1. Start command line with `"path to chromium or chrome" --load-extension="path to Restore URL folder"`  and/or
2. add `--load-extension="path to Restore URL folder"` at the end of the target field in your Desktop / Taskbar shortcut

Replace text in quotes with actual path
(Credit to [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784332) for this)

Up until Chrome 82, using the above method would result in a dismissable popup - "disable developer mode extensions" - every time you restart Chrome.

In Chrome 83 and later, there are no more popups and no downsides to this method except taking a bit of time to setup.

Comment: It's a duplicate of an older [existing answer](/a/1498561) which has an explanation.